# Change the background color of the added shape file in rasterVis levelplot

Tags: r, plot, raster, lattice, r-raster

I want to change the oceans color (outside of the shapefile boundry). I can clip the raster and change the background color, but here I want to do that with the added shapefile.

```
library(raster)
library(rasterVis)
library(maps)
library(maptools)
library(mapdata)

r <- raster(nrow=361, ncol=576, ymn=-90, ymx=90) 
values(r) <- 1:ncell(r)
data(wrld_simpl, package = "maptools")
levelplot(r)+ layer(sp.polygons(wrld_simpl, lwd=0.1, col='gray'))
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, mask the Raster with the SpatialPolygons object. Cells not covered
by it are set to NA.

```
land <- mask(r, wrld_simpl)
```

Now, change the background color (used for the NA cells):

```
catTheme <- rasterTheme(panel.background = list(col='lightskyblue1'))
```

And finally, display the result:

```
levelplot(land, par.settings = catTheme) +
    layer(sp.polygons(wrld_simpl,
                      lwd=0.1, col='gray'))
```

[image: levelplot]

Comment: Thank you but this way it fills the polygons, I want to change the ocean color.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. I will modify my answer.

Comment: Thank you, there is still a problem and its that if you have missing values in land they will have the same color as the ocean. I was hoping to find a way to change the colors of outside of the boundary of the shape file only.

Comment: A solution is to assign a extreme value to those missing values in land.

Comment: or another option is using an ocean shape file instead of land.